# VGG bottleneck features + LSTM in keras

Tags: keras, lstm, vgg-net

I have pre-stored bottleneck features (.npy files) obtained from VGG16 for around 10k images. Training a SVM classifier (3-class classification) on these features gave me an accuracy of 90% on the test set. These images are obtained from videos. I want to train an LSTM in keras on top of these features. My code snippet can be found below. The issue is that the training accuracy is not going above 43%, which is unexpected. Please help me in debugging the issue. I have tried with different learning rates.

```
#Asume all necessary imports done
classes = 3
frames = 5
channels = 3
img_height = 224
img_width = 224
epochs = 20

#Model definition
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten(),input_shape=(frames,7,7,512)))
model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1024,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(3,activation="softmax"))
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.1,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=None,decay=0.0)

model.compile (loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=optimizer,metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()

train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy','rb'))

#final_img_data shape --> 2342,5,7,7,512
#one_hot_labels shape --> 2342,3
model.fit(final_img_data,one_hot_labels,epochs=epochs,batch_size=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the local minimum, because learning rate is too high. Try to decrease `learning rate` to 0.01 -- 0.001 and increase number of `epochs`. Also, decrease `Dense` layer neurons from 1024 to half. Otherwise you may overfit.